# Find the volume of $E$ bounded by $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \leq 1$ and $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{xy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

I am in the process of finding the volume of the solid $E$, where

$$E = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x > 0, y > 0, \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \leq 1, 0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{xy} \}.$$

Now, this is an exercise that is found in the change of variable section of a real analysis textbook, so I thought I could apply some $u$ and $v$ substitution. But no attempts, out of the many I've tried so far, has worked, including:

1. $u = v = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$, where the Jacobian determinant would be $0$.
2. Splitting the domain equation into $0 \lt \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \leq 1$ and swapping some terms back and forth.
3. Substituting with $u = \sqrt{x}$ and $v = \sqrt{y}$ and applying various techniques. In this case I wasn't able to find $a, b, c$ and $d$ s.t. $a \leq u \leq b$, $c \leq v \leq d$.

Comment: Hint: Let $D=\{(x,y): x > 0, y > 0, \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \leq 1\}$ and then
$$ V=\iint_{D}\sqrt{xy}\;dxdy $$

Comment: This is something I've already experimented with. I just have no clue of how to find the integration extremes, if that is something that needs to be done at all.

Comment: use $x=r^2\cos^4t,y=r^2\sin^4t$.

Comment: Where does that relation come from? If it's a polar substitution I cannot use it, since it hasn't still been introduced in this section of the book. Anyway, by noting that $x \gt 0$ we have, combining the definition of $D$: $\sqrt{x} \leq 1 - \sqrt{y} \iff x \leq  1 - 2\sqrt{y} + y \implies 0 \le x \leq 1 - 2 \sqrt{y} + y.$

Comment: You can use $$ V=\iint_{D}\sqrt{xy}\;dxdy=\int_0^1\sqrt xdx\int_0^{(1-\sqrt x)^2}\sqrt ydy. $$

Comment: Where would you find out the first extreme in $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}dx \cdots dy$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $D=\{(x,y): x > 0, y > 0, \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \leq 1\}$ and then
$$ V=\iint_{D}\sqrt{xy}\;dxdy=\int_0^1\sqrt xdx\int_0^{(1-\sqrt x)^2}\sqrt ydy. $$
You can handle the rest.